# java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address on Heroku

Tags: java, sockets, heroku, spark-java

After deploying to Heroku, Spark server crashes with this exception. My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver=$PORT -jar target/myappname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

From what I understand, Heroku assigns a new PORT every time the app is deployed. However, I am getting the PORT value from the environment variable set by Heroku, so why can't I get this requested address?

Edit: These are my error logs after correcting the Procfile to -Dserver.port=$PORT.

```
2015-11-21T16:45:02.832568+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2015-11-21T16:45:04.061714+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-1] ERROR spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - ignite failed
2015-11-21T16:45:03.918669+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @1084ms
2015-11-21T16:45:03.989340+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-1] INFO spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - == Spark has ignited ...
2015-11-21T16:45:03.989452+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-1] INFO spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - >> Listening on myappname.herokuapp.com:27925
2015-11-21T16:45:03.998409+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
2015-11-21T16:45:04.062462+00:00 app[web.1]: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
2015-11-21T16:45:04.062702+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065229+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065305+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065472+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065412+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065575+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065628+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065688+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.065758+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.067368+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.067370+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.067370+00:00 app[web.1]:    at spark.webserver.JettySparkServer.ignite(JettySparkServer.java:131)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.067371+00:00 app[web.1]:    at spark.SparkInstance.lambda$init$0(SparkInstance.java:341)
2015-11-21T16:45:04.067372+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-21T16:45:05.052415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-21T16:45:05.036728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 100
```

This happened after adding --port $PORT. Basically, I see no change in the error.

```
2015-11-21T17:51:14.666062+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @230ms
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779260+00:00 app[web.1]: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779449+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.721317+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-0] INFO spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - == Spark has ignited ...
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779526+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779573+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.721319+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-0] INFO spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - >> Listening on myappname.herokuapp.com:29822
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779601+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779661+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.721320+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779796+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779732+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.778639+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thread-0] ERROR spark.webserver.JettySparkServer - ignite failed
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779884+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779949+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.779980+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.780034+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.780071+00:00 app[web.1]:    at spark.webserver.JettySparkServer.ignite(JettySparkServer.java:131)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.780110+00:00 app[web.1]:    at spark.SparkInstance.lambda$init$0(SparkInstance.java:341)
2015-11-21T17:51:14.780153+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-21T17:51:15.393560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 100
2015-11-21T17:51:15.399506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: How to write this kind of Procfile? I have been searching for a long time including [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and other questions in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem is that I was setting the domain's IP address in my main method. It seems that we shouldn't be setting this, but only setting the PORT by getting it from the environment variable $PORT.

Comment: so if this answered your question, accept your own anser

Comment: I cannot do that right now, I need to wait a day before I do it. I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @user16342blue Can you please specify what is "environment variable $PORT"? I meet the same problem now. I am keep trying for almost two days (40 hours).

Comment: I think this sentence will help me - *but only setting the PORT by getting it from the environment variable $PORT*, but I don't know how to do that. Assume that I use MongoHQ on Heroku as my database, and I can got the port is **10385**, do you mean I just directly use port("10385") in the main method?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dserver.port=$PORT` in Procfile instead of `-Dserver=$PORT` and deploy the app. 
Post the exact error which your are getting in the logs if the error persists.

Comment: I added the error logs to my original question. These appeared in the logs after changing the Procfile as you said. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also try using --port $PORT

Comment: I tried this, edited the question to add the error logs for this.

Comment: Are you running any embedded server from you main class?

Comment: I am not sure, I am starting a Spark Java server from the main class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, That's wierd, I believe the app is already running and its trying to assign the same address and port which it should not. One last try that I would do is to stop the running app using 'heroku ps:scale web=0 -a <appname>' and then 'heroku ps:scale web=1 -a <appname> to start the app.

Comment: What is the **<appname>** here? Is it the name appeared in heroku like *aqueous-journey-2399*?